# Different result for web and API query

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a quick script using python to return estimated number of query results. This is my attempt

```
import urllib
import json

songs = ["Jimmy Fallon", "test2", "another test"]
query = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&q=%s"

google_hits = list()
for song in songs:
    results = urllib.urlopen(query % (song))
    json_res = json.loads(results.read())
    google_hits.append(int(json_res['responseData']['cursor']['estimatedResultCount']))

print google_hits
```

However, the script and regular query using browser gives totally different numbers. How can I retrieve the numbers returned by the browser using python API, even if it's deprecated.

Comment: Are you sure that both query types are entirely equivalent?

Comment: IIRC - I don't believe even when Google offered this way of searching  that it ever even implied the number of results or the actual results would be identical. So if you get totally different numbers - I think it's working fine ;)

Comment: Google changes the results it gives back on a number of factors, like your IP location but it also personalizes your results. It also personalizes results in your browser. It's unlikely you'll be able to get the same exact results.

Comment: Probably worth noting that you aren't escaping your url parameters

Comment: FWIW, you should use `urlencode` to build the query URL which might be quite important for the "another test" case (including a space). Examples: http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#examples

Comment: @Jan-Philip Gehrcke: I'm sure they are not equivalent and that's why I posted question to know what might be different.

Comment: @Jon Clements: for first query web returns `17.600.000` results and python only `2.260.000`. Little too much difference to ignore...

Comment: @Pablo it's no longer supported (so you can't ask Google for canonical info.)- it never returned the same results/counts anyway - what answer would you be happy to accept to this question?

Comment: Here we go "Jimmy Fallon" - searching via the API gives me 28,000,000 and typing the same into google.com gives: 47,900,000. So I'm closer, but we still have no comparable figures... where do you want to go now?

Comment: @Jon Clements: The answer which has an example of some api which I can use in Python to get result closer to web result.

Comment: @Pablo okay - automate a web browser using Selenium HQ, then scrape the DOM to receive *exactly* the same results. There is no API route... Unlike Yahoo/Bing - Google do not want you doing web searches  like that anymore...